# How to delete a video file if the user interrupted the download?

Tags: node.js, express, file-upload, multer

I am doing file uploads using a Multer.
When the file has successfully uploaded, I get the path to the video and can delete it, but if the user interrupted the download, the Multer still uploads part of the file to the downloads folder, but does not give the path to the video file, how can I delete such files in this case ?

```
const multer = require('multer');

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, 'upload/');
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, `${req.user.id}-${Date.now()}-${file.originalname}`);
    }
});


const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
    if(
        file.mimetype === 'image/png' ||
        file.mimetype === 'image/jpg' ||
        file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg' ||
        file.mimetype === 'video/mp4'
    ) {
        cb(null, true);
    } else {
        cb(null, false);
    }
};


const uploadConfig = multer({
    storage: storage,
    fileFilter: fileFilter,
    limits: {fileSize: 1000000000 * 10},
    preservePath: true
});


router.post('/upload-content', isAuth, uploadConfig.any(), async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        res.status(201).json({
            message: 'Saved successful',
            contentType: req.files[0].mimetype,
            fileName: req.files[0].filename,
            fileOriginalName: req.files[0].originalname,
            fileSize: req.files[0].size,
            filePath: req.files[0].path
      })
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is a multer-issue that has been around for a couple of years now, see this related github issue: https://github.com/expressjs/multer/issues/259

I suggest you try to implement one of the [proposed workaround](https://github.com/expressjs/multer/issues/259#issuecomment-691748926)s, we're using the same in our app and it has been working fine so far.

Comment: @EkVision: any feedback? If this answered your question, please mark it as accepted by clicking the checkmark on the left.